# MVC model update and create (multiple) at the same time using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Controller including:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Hoạt_động act= db.Hoạt_động.Find(id); ;
    if (act== null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    IList<SelectListItem> mt = new List<SelectListItem>();

    Dropdownlist();

    return View(act);
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Mã_Hoạt_động, Hoạt_Động, Mã_Chương_trình, Loại_hình, Thông_tin, Đáp_án, ActNội_dung, Thời_gian, Thời_gian_Kết_thúc, Thông_Báo, NoteNội_dung, Ngày")]MultipleActivityEditClass mt)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MultipleActivityEd(mt.Mã_Hoạt_động, mt.Hoạt_Động, mt.Loại_hình, mt.Thông_tin, mt.Đáp_án, mt.ActNội_dung, mt.Thời_gian, mt.Thời_gian_Kết_thúc, mt.Thông_Báo, mt.NoteNội_dung, mt.Ngày);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Mã_Chương_trình = new SelectList(db.Chương_trình, "Mã_Chương_trình", "Tên", mt.Mã_Chương_trình);
    return View(mt);
}
```

**MultipleActivityEd** Class

```
public class MultipleActivityEditClass
{
    public Nullable<int> Mã_Hoạt_động { get; }
    public string Hoạt_Động { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Mã_Chương_trình { get; set; }
    public string Loại_hình { get; set; }
    public string Thông_tin { get; set; }
    public string Đáp_án { get; set; }
    public string ActNội_dung { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Thời_gian { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Thời_gian_Kết_thúc { get; set; }

    //Another table
    public string Thông_Báo { get; set; }
    public string NoteNội_dung { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Ngày { get; set; }

}
```

I get a problem that the **Edit** controller do not accept **act** as parameter.

Throw an exception--

> "this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'WebApplication1.Models.MultipleActivityEditClass'"

I do not know how to fix this problem or convert **act** into the required model item.

The stored procedure:

```
    @Id int,
    @ActName varchar(50),
    @Mã_Chương_trình int,
    @Loại_hình varchar(50),
    @Thông_tin varchar(50),
    @Đáp_án varchar(50),
    @ActNội_dung varchar(50),
    @Thời_gian datetime,
    @Thời_gian_Kết_thúc datetime,

    @NoteName varchar(50),
    @NoteNội_dung varchar(MAX),
    @Ngày date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    update [Hoạt động]
    set 
    Tên = @ActName,
    [Mã Chương trình] = @Mã_Chương_trình,
    [Loại hình] = @Loại_hình,
    [Thông tin] = @Thông_tin,
    [Đáp án] = @Đáp_án,
    [Nội dung] = @ActNội_dung,
    [Thời gian] = @Thời_gian,
    [Thời gian Kết thúc] = @Thời_gian_Kết_thúc
    where [Mã Hoạt động] = @Id

    insert into [Thông báo]([Mã Hoạt động],Tên,[Nội dung],Ngày)
    values(@Id,@NoteName,@NoteNội_dung,@Ngày)
END
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Entity.  Entity has a mapping file that maps the database tables/properties to the c# classes.  The mapping file needs to be refreshed.  You changed either the database or the c# classes and now the mapping is inconsistent.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET 4.6 MVC model, how do you make sure the mapping is consistent? Also are there anyway to check the consistency of it when you making change?

Comment: The problem is I failed to convert from the db entity into the class. I have found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add convert lines:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Hoạt_động act= db.Hoạt_động.Find(id); ;
    if (act== null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    //Add these lines
    MultipleActivityEditClass mte = new MultipleActivityEditClass();
    mte.Mã_Hoạt_động = act.Mã_Hoạt_động;
    mte.Hoạt_Động = act.Tên;
    mte.Mã_Chương_trình = act.Mã_Chương_trình;
    mte.Loại_hình = act.Loại_hình;
    mte.Thông_tin = act.Thông_tin;
    mte.Đáp_án = act.Đáp_án;
    mte.ActNội_dung = act.Nội_dung;
    mte.Thời_gian = act.Thời_gian;
    mte.Thời_gian_Kết_thúc = act.Thời_gian_Kết_thúc;


    Dropdownlist();

    return View(act);
}
```

Still a clunky method to return value to the View, but it work so far